# Mysql Extract max number from a string

Tags: mysql, string, numbers, max, extract

Do you know if there is any manner to extract maximum number into a string in MySql ?

My table looks like this:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| Freq                                                      |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| 40.56                                                     |
| 99.51                                                     |
| 99.87                                                     |
| T=0.00, TCCA=0.00, TTCC=0.03, TTCG=0.00, TTCT=55.0        |
| C=97.70, T=0.05                                           | 
| 44.61                                                     |
| 57.45                                                     |
| 38.18                                                     |
| 38.43                                                     |
| 39.36                                                     |
| 38.65                                                     |
| 39.30                                                     |
| C=57.53, T=0.17                                           |
| TAAAAAAAAAAA=0.51, TAAAAAAAAAA=68.03, TAAAAAAAAAAAG=31.42 |
+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Desired output**:

```
55.0
97.70
```

Comment: Can you change your table design? It is bad.

Comment: That doesn't look much like a table. :-(

Comment: I just put Freq columun which is varchar. Some rows contains only numbers and some others are mixed with string and numbers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the maximum value in a comma separated field in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9810034/how-do-i-get-the-maximum-value-in-a-comma-separated-field-in-mysql)

Comment: not really, because there is a string in some certains rows